# How to use colored icons for autocomplete menu nvim.coc?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, neovim-qt

I am using neovim-qt for typescript react development. From last week I am configuring my neovim. I have configured `coc.nvim` which is giving pretty good autocompletion. I wanted to add icons for completion item kind. I did that setting `suggest.completionItemKindLabels` in `CocConfig`. The icons are showing fine. The only thing now I want is to add custom color to each icon. For now they are just showing same as the color of autocomplete text.

Is this something to do with colorscheme. I am using gruvbox.

```
  "suggest.completionItemKindLabels": {
    "variable": "\uf71b",
    "constant": "\uf8ff",
    "struct": "\ufb44",
    "class": "\uf0e8",
    "interface": "\ufa52",
    "text": "\ue612",
    "enum": "\uf435",
    "enumMember": "\uf02b",
    "color": "\ue22b",
    "property": "\ufab6",
    "field": "\uf93d",
    "unit": "\uf475",
    "file": "\uf471",
    "value": "\uf8a3",
    "event": "\ufacd",
    "folder": "\uf115",
    "keyword": "\uf893",
    "snippet": "\uf64d",
    "operator": "\uf915",
    "reference": "\uf87a",
    "typeParameter": "\uf278",
    "default": "\uf29c"
  }
```

For now icons are just showing as

[image]

**Note**: I am using webdevicons and also install nerd font on my system. The icons in explorer are colored but inside editor they are not.

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion: did you try ANSI colors?

Vim is a command line application and as so it uses ANSI colors to color every terminal column. So thus maybe you could color the icon that is going to be printed.

Here is a more complete doc about how to use ANSI colors: [bash-colors.md](https://github.com/pandasoli/posts/blob/master/bash-colors.md).

> You could try this line for example:
>   `"struct": "\033[31m\ufb44",`
> In theory it would print the icon with the color red.

I tried to test it before commenting here, but for me as for a lot of people `coc.nvim` is not showing icons. I'll figure it out with time.

Thx for the welcoming!

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer. To me, it sounds a little bit like a comment. Does this actually answer the question or was it only meant as a suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure how ANSI colors are intended to solve this problem. Perhaps [edit] and clarify? Welcome to [vi.se]!